# How to count number of significant p-values in a simulation?

Tags: r, loops, simulation

Say I have a clinical trial where there are 32 mice are infected with a disease. I treat 16 of them with my treatment, and leave the other 16 as control. Before conducting the experiment, I am running a simulation. I will draw 32 observations from a uniform(0,1) distribution. I would like to count the number of times that I achieved a p-value of < 0.01 after the simulations are over. I feel like I am almost there, but I don't know how to put it together:

```
nSims <- 10000 #number of simulated experiments
p <-numeric(nSims) #set up empty container for all simulated p-values
sig<-0
for(i in 1:nSims){ #for each simulated experiment

   #generating 32 observations total from uniform(0,1) distribution
   control.year1 <- runif(16, min = 0, max = 1)
   treat.year1 <- runif(16, min = 0, max = 1)

   #Creating dichotomous variable for those get better/don't get better
   control.respond <- ifelse(control.year1<=0.05,1,0)
   treat.respond <- ifelse(treat.year1<=0.30,1,0)

   #perform t-test
   z <- t.test(control.respond,treat.respond) 
   p[i]<-z$p.value #get the p-value and store it

   # want to count number of significant p-values - not sure how to do it
   significance <- ifelse(z$p.value<= 0.01,sum(sig, 1),0)
}
```

Comment: You should be able to count the number of significant results at the end, outside of the for loop, with `sum(p < 0.01)`. But you are running a t-test on a binary outcome? I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to work this out analytically?

Comment: you might be interested in some of the built-in power calculators in R (`apropos("^power")`)

Comment: @BenBolker  thanks, this is not the final simulation - I am simulating a five year experiment that may stop early if treatment is effective, I am just trying to get the loop for the first year of the experiment right.

Comment: @Marius Thanks for the heads up, you are right, I am going to use a one sided fisher's exact test.

Comment: @Mob I could, but for this simulation I am simulating an experiment that will run for 5 years but may stop early if treatment is effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not the most elegant but uses `magrittr` and `dplyr` for data handling. First I created a matrix to hold your simulated data:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

n <- 100
control.years <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(16*n, min=0, max=1),ncol=16))
treat.years <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(16*n, min=0, max=1),ncol=16))
```

Then I created a data structure to capture the p-values for all t-tests:

```
for (i in 1:n) { p[i] <- t.test(control.years[i,],treat.years[i,])$p.value }
```

You can filter out p-values in the range you like:

```
> as.data.frame(p) %>% filter(p<0.05)
       p
1 0.03173299
2 0.01652114
3 0.00471807
```

Or you can create a new variable that tells you whether significant or not:

```
> as.data.frame(p) %>% mutate(sig=ifelse(p<0.05,1,0)) 
             p sig
1   0.65233254   0
2   0.50731231   0
3   0.11657045   0
...
29  0.03173299   1
```

Or you can find out how many significant p-values:

```
> z <- as.data.frame(p) %>% mutate(sig=ifelse(p<0.05,1,0)) 
> table(z$sig)

 0  1 
97  3
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was thinking of, and thanks for the different options.